# Am I using as.numeric incorrectly? (Still says the argument isn't numeric)

Tags: r

Edit: I have made the change but I am still getting an error

```
data <- readLines(con = stdin(), n = 3)[[2]]

weights <- readLines(con = stdin(), n = 3)[[3]]

cat(weighted.mean(as.numeric(data), as.numeric(weights)))
```

And the new output:

```
Error in as.numeric(weights) : 
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
Calls: cat -> weighted.mean -> weighted.mean.default
In addition: Warning message:
In weighted.mean(as.numeric(data), as.numeric(weights), na.rm = TRUE) :
NAs introduced by coercion
Execution halted
```

I don't understand how the argument is still not numeric after using as.numeric.  I am trying to read in two arrays and find the weighted mean.  The output 1,2,3 and 4,5,6 was just a sample input I entered.

```
data <- readLines(con = stdin(), n = 3)[[2]]

as.numeric(data)

weights <- readLines(con = stdin(), n = 3)[[3]]

as.numeric(weights)

cat(weighted.mean(data, weights))
```

And this is my output:

```
> data <- readLines(con = stdin(), n = 3)[[2]]
1
2
3
> as.numeric(data)
[1] 2
> weights <- readLines(con = stdin(), n = 3)[[3]]
4
5
6
> as.numeric(weights)
[1] 6
> cat(weighted.mean(data, weights))
Error in x * w : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: You need to save the results of as.numeric. For example `data<-as.numeric(data)`. Generally functions in R don't have side effects and return new, updated objects.

Comment: Did you copy/paste those lines exactly as they appear in your question? The error message sounds like you made a typo and saved the results of `readLines` to some other variable name. And changing your question to ask a different question is frowned upon. If you get a different error (a different problem to solve), you should start a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`weighted.mean` doesn't convert character to numeric for you. You merely printed their `as.numeric` output to the shell and forgot the two arguments to `weighted.mean` were characters.